# Cannot bulk load because the file "\\servername......ispac" could not be opened.SQL Server Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I'm having a situation that I have 2 servers A and B. I'm running sql 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''\serverB\file.ispac'', SINGLE_BLOB) as BinaryData)'.

The ispac file is on server B. Both sqlserver use the same windows authentication, If I run the sql on SSMS on server A then it's a success. But if I login to server A with SSMS using the same windows authentication on ServerB and run the sql in SSMS, it then shows error:

Cannot bulk load because the file "\serverB\file.ispac" could not be opened.SQL Server Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"

Any idea what's the cause?

Comment: Is there meant to be a share name as part of the UNC path? e.g.: `'\\ServerB\ShareName\file.ispac'`

Comment: What permissions does the share have? Does the SQL Server service on ServerA have permissions on the share? (unlikely given it's a local user account not a domain account)

Comment: it's a domain account, and it has the share permission, that's why 'If I run the sql on SSMS on server A then it's a success.'